# Use fs-extra on .bundle file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bundle, fs

I'm trying to check if a specific folder within my project contains a `.bundle` file and if it does, move it somewhere, otherwise use a default. The issue I'm having is that I can't see to check if the file exists using `fs-extra`.

This is what I have right now, if it exists or doesn't, it still logs true.

```
fs.exists(themeDir + "Lights.bundle").then(() => {
  console.log("true");
}
```

From what I've read it should throw a promise error if the file does not exist.

Comment: You don't `catch` anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to use `fs.existsSync()`

```
var lightsBundlePath = buildDir + `templates/Lights.bundle`;

if ((themeLightsBundle = fs.existsSync(themeDir + `Lights.bundle`))) {
  lightsBundlePath = themeLightsBundle;
}
```